# WebApi return json vs return OK(json)

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I was watching a video on micro-services, and I noticed something that deviated from the way I usually do things.  I'm wondering what the benefits are of using ActionResult vs returning plain Json

```
[HttpGet()]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Products>>> GetProducts()
{
     var products = await this._repo.GetProducts();
     return Ok(products);
}

[HttpGet()]
public Task<IEnumerable<Products>> GetProducts()
{
     return this._repo.GetProducts();
}
```

Why would someone return ActionResult, if they could just return the products directly?

Comment: Because you could use it with an [http status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) other than 200 (ok) and still use a strongly typed result.

Comment: @Igor,  Thanks, just to clarify,  When would a strongly typed result be useful in WebApi?  Since no one consumes the controllers,  The only use case I can think of would be from the Razor Pages in MVC.

Comment: Or I guess it would be also useful to abstract throwing custom HttpErrors for 404 etc, but even then I don't see much of a benefit

Comment: Unit tests, razor pages, web api documentation builders, and type safety (example calling through to a method in another type and returning that result, should that method's return type change it should cause a compile time error).

Comment: @igor if you post the comments as an answer I will accept

Comment: @igor still there igor? ;) Looks like you've got another green check on the way.